# If you open more applications than can be shown in the Launcher

Tags: sentence-construction

I'm reading about the document of Ubuntu, and I don't understand the structure of sentence below.

> If you open more applications than can be shown in the Launcher, the
>   Launcher will “fold” the application icons at the bottom of the Launcher.

I see there are two verbs (*open* and *show*) in a sentence and it's not clear.

Comment: The Launcher has space to show the icons for only a limited number of applications. If you open more applications than that number, the Launcher "folds" the display.

Comment: The sentence is grammatical, by the way. *Than* replaces the subject, and in some dialects you might hear *than what* instead. You shouldn't use *what* there, but it might help you understand the structure to some degree.

Comment: Structurally it's the same as [the Micawber principle](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Micawber_principle), which can be succinctly stated as *If you spend more than you earn, you will be miserable*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I don't understand 
 [the Micawber principle](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Micawber_principle)

Comment: **open** is a predicate of "you", so  **can be shown** is predicate of which?

Comment: @Pham Van Duc: That surprises me, but it's not essential to understand that particular principle to see how the *syntax* works. As an alternative, consider *If you eat more than you need, you will get fat.*

Comment: @PhamVanDuc *If you open more applications than **the number of applications** that can be shown in the Launcher...*

Comment: @FumbleFingers , I don't realise the structure of my sentence is the same as [the Micawber principle](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Micawber_principle)

Comment: I have a similar sentence: **These separate views of your desktop allow you to group applications together** . Two verbs (separate and allow) . what is The subject of each verb?

Comment: @PhamVanDuc *Separate* isn't a verb there, but an adjective. In the future, don't ask entirely new questions in the comments.

Comment: Yes, but How do I know **separate** is an adjective while it is also a verb?

Comment: @PhamVanDuc Read more and it'll all become clear.

Answer (score 1):

@StoneyB answered in a comment:

> The Launcher has space to show the icons for only a limited number of applications. If you open more applications than that number, the Launcher "folds" the display.